# Launch4J not recognizing Eclipse Temurin OpenJDK Java 17

Tags: java, maven, launch4j

I'm using Windows 10 and I have Java 17 installed, with `JAVA_HOME` set correctly. `java --version` gives this:

```
openjdk 17.0.2 2022-01-18
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-17.0.2+8 (build 17.0.2+8)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Temurin-17.0.2+8 (build 17.0.2+8, mixed mode, sharing)
```

In a Maven parent POM I have Launch4j via the `launch4j-maven-plugin` 2.1.1 configured to generate an EXE using my current JRE:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>com.akathist.maven.plugins.launch4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>launch4j-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.1</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>generate-exe</id>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>launch4j</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
      ...
      <jre>
        <minVersion>${maven.compiler.release}</minVersion>
      </jre>
...
```

This parent POM also specifies Java 8 (although it requires Java 9+ to build):

```
<properties>
  <maven.compiler.release>8</maven.compiler.release>
...
```

My CLI project POM uses the parent POM above. I build the Maven project with no problem, and it generates `my-cli.exe`. I can run `my-cli.exe` just fine.

But I want to use Java 17 in the My CLI, which should be fine since I have Java 17 installed. So I set the following in the My ClI project:

```
<properties>
  <maven.compiler.release>17</maven.compiler.release>
...
```

I clean and rebuild the project, and it outputs `my-cli.exe` just as before. But when I try to run `my-cli.exe`, it prints:

```
My CLI: This application requires a Java Runtime Environment 17
```

Then it opens my browser to `https://java.com/en/download/`.

From [Launch4J Bug 197](https://sourceforge.net/p/launch4j/bugs/197/), it appears that Launch4J doesn't look at the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable, but instead looks at the Windows registry. That means it ignores any manually-installed JDKs.  So I went to [Adoptium](https://adoptium.net/) and used the installer to install the latest release, `OpenJDK17U-jdk_x64_windows_hotspot_17.0.2_8.msi`. In my Windows installed programs, it shows "Eclipse Temurin JDK with Hotspot 17.0.2+8 (x64). Unfortunately the same thing happens; Launch4J still doesn't recognize it.

Why is Launch4J not recognizing that OpenJDK 17.0.2+8 is a "Java Runtime Environment 17"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Launch4j documentation](https://launch4j.sourceforge.net/docs.html#Configuration_file) for the `<path>` element describes the solution:

> ... it is possible to use the JAVA_HOME or PATH
> environment variables to search for a runtime that was installed
> without adding registry keys used for searching JREs.

So just add `path` element to your `launch4j-maven-plugin` configuration:

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>com.akathist.maven.plugins.launch4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>launch4j-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.2</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        ...
        <configuration>
          ...
          <jre>
            <path>%JAVA_HOME%;%PATH%</path>
```

Comment: Hi, Ilya. I had actually found that out in a longer discussion I had on [Launch4J Bug 197](https://sourceforge.net/p/launch4j/bugs/197/), but I had forgotten to update my answer. Thanks for writing this. I updated my answer just now, but I'll mark your response as the answer for your trouble of posting it and for reminding me.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently as per [Launch4J Feature Request 103](https://sourceforge.net/p/launch4j/feature-requests/103/), Launch4J doesn't look at the same registry keys that OpenJDK uses, and only works with Oracle JDK registry keys. There's an [Adoptium Issue 64](https://github.com/adoptium/installer/issues/64) which requests that Adoptium use the same registry keys as Oracle, but it looks like this was abandoned because of gotchas.

As noted in the feature request above, Launch4J should be looking at the `JAVA_HOME` environment anyway. After more extensive discussion on [Launch4J Bug 197](https://sourceforge.net/p/launch4j/bugs/197/), I discovered it is now possible to specify the search path to include `%JAVA_HOME%`, using something like, as noted in Ilya's answer:

```xml
<jre>
  <path>%JAVA_HOME%;%PATH%</path>
</jre>
```

It's also possible to change the URL that is launched if no JDK is found to something more useful, or (perhaps more appropriate for a CLI program) remove it altogether. Read [Launch4J Bug 197](https://sourceforge.net/p/launch4j/bugs/197/) for more details.

Comment: bundle the JRE.  That is what Oracle wants you to anyway

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue (maven plugin version 2.5, Java17/Liberica Bellsoft) where the JRE could not be found -whilst it was just there-.

Finally with the`--l4j-debug-all` option I saw that the JRE directory was found but that the `-version` output of java was not correctly detected.

As a workaround I disabled the bitLevel and version

```
<jre>
    <path>${project.jre.version}</path>
    <!--requires64Bit>true</requires64Bit-->
    <!--minVersion>17.0.10</minVersion-->
    <requiresJdk>false</requiresJdk>
</jre>
```

Comment: probably we need to wait for a new version: https://sourceforge.net/u/dpolivaev/launch4j/ci/41bc3ba1b3622c52f75b31ca0beb11d7cb067b24/